# Firestore - How to apply 'string contains' condition on a field while querying?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

```
Collection - Post
{
  "postId" : "post_124",
  "title" : "World population 2020"
}
```

How to write a query that returns posts having the string "World population" in the "title" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore doesn't support this level of query.  See [Full-text search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) for a possible work-around/solution.  The only expressions available are:

<, <=, ==, >, >=, array-contains, in, or array-contains-any.