# Get documents with query on document id in Cloud Functions and Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a trigger on update document in firestore cloud function, in this function I want to get documents that contain a specific string.
so I tried this:

```
const chat_threads = admin.firestore().collectionGroup('chatThreads').where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),'array-contains', reciever_id).get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

but I get this error

> Error: Invalid Query. You can't perform 'array-contains' queries on FieldPath.documentId().

Is there another way to get the result? or what can I use instead of `array-contains`

Comment: ```admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()``` is the document id. It's a string, not an array. Can you tell us more about what you're trying to do? It looks as if you're trying to get all the documents in your collection that has a specific ID. But if that's the case, why not just retrieve that document by itself using the ID? You wouldn't need the ```where``` query because you already know the ID

Comment: I'm trying to get all documents that contains a specific substring, I didn't know at first that it is wrong to use array-contains, but now it is clear to me, thanks for the clarification. @S.Ramjit

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get documents that contain a specific string

Firestore doesn't have a way to find documents with arbitrary substrings. It can do prefix filtering (so a string that starts with a specific value), but no other substring matching.

This has been covered a few times before, so have a look at:

- [Firestore get document that contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579085/firestore-get-document-that-contains-a-string/63579770#63579770)
- [SELECT where document field contains the string in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433447/select-where-document-field-contains-the-string-in-firestore)
- [Firestore - How to apply 'string contains' condition on a field while querying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760663/firestore-how-to-apply-string-contains-condition-on-a-field-while-querying)

While these are not specific to document IDs (as you need), the same limits (and solutions/workarounds) apply here.